# Filtro para selecionar conteúdo

Tags: html

boa tarde.

Estou tentando criar um filtro que exibe somente o conteúdo de elementos ativados, desativados e todos.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme no exemplo acima, eu tenho um select com as opções (Todas , Ativas e Encerradas) o conceito é, ao clicar em todas, irá aparecer tanto as divs ativas como encerradas. Ao clicar em ativas, irá exibir somente as ativas e encerradas somente as encerradas.

Eu não consegui achar um plugin que execute essa funcionalidade, será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado

Segue o html

```html
<div class="filtros">
<div class="reg-title col-md-2 col-lg-2">
<p> Visualizar: </p>
</div>
<div class="reg-title col-md-3 col-lg-3">
<select id="cp-gifts">
    <option value="todas">Todas</option>                           
    <option value="ativas">Ativas</option>

    <option value="encerradas">Encerradas</option>                           
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">


<section class="div1">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<article class="col">
<div class="box-regulamento">
<h3>Promoção Ativa</h3>
<br>
<span>Validade da promoção: </span>

<p>02/01/19 a 06/03/19</p>
<br>
<a class="btn-primary button-gift" href="https://www.pontoslivelo.com.br/regulamento" target="_blank">Saiba Mais</a></div>
</article>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<article class="col">
<div class="div2">
<h3>Promocao Encerrada</h3>
<br>
<span>Validade da promoção: </span>

<p>01/02/19 a 31/02/10</p>
<br>
<a class="btn-primary button-gift" href="https://www.pontoslivelo.com.br/regulamento" target="_blank">Saiba Mais</a></div>
</article>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: O que você conhece de Html, Css e Javascript? O que já tentou de código?

Comment: LeAndrade, eu apenas desenvolvi o layout conforme exemplo da imagem, fiz utilizando o Bootstrap, mas queria saber como faço para desenvolver esse dinâmica que citei acima. Quero apenas o caminho para eu mesmo aprender. Obrigado

Comment: Quais ferramentas deseja utilizar para desenvolver isto? Html, jQuery? E poste qualquer código mesmo que só o Html para podermos ter um ponto de partida!

Comment: Eu acabei de postar o código, gostaria de fazer isso via jquery, é possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo bem básico seguindo seu exemplo utilizando **jQuery**, basicamente o que você faz é a cada mudança no `select` ele mostra o **card** conforme o value do select:

```js
$(function() {
  let filtro = $('#filter');
  
  filtro.on('change', function() {
    if(filtro.val() == 'active') {
      $('.card1').show();
      $('.card2').hide();
    } else if(filtro.val() == 'closed') {
      $('.card2').show();
      $('.card1').hide();
    } else {
      $('.card1, .card2').show();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.cards {
  width: 45%;
  background-color: #CCC !important;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn {
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="filter">
  <option>Todas</option>
  <option value="active">Ativas</option>
  <option value="closed">Encerradas</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cards card1">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Promoção Ativa</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Validade da promoção:
02/01/19 a 06/03/19</p>
        <p class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">data</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Saiba mais</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cards card2">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Promoção Encerrada</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Validade da promoção:
01/02/19 a 31/02/10</p>
        <p class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">expirada</p>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Saiba mais</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mano, era exatamente isso que eu precisava, muito obrigado cara, vlw

Comment: Por nada man!!!